Using MDX and rehype-highlight on a next.js website to render an MD containing code causes Object.hasOwn crash
I have pretty standard setup that is closely based on the examples from next.js and next-mdx-remote. Everything works, until I add rehypeHighlight to the rehypePlugins array. Then I get this error, any idea why that would happen? Thanks.

TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function

import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight"

export async function getPostData(id) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const {content, data} = matter(fileContents)

    const mdxSource = await serialize(content, {
        // Optionally pass remark/rehype plugins
        mdxOptions: {
            remarkPlugins: [],
            rehypePlugins: [rehypeHighlight],
        },
        scope: data,
    });

    // Combine the data with the id and contentHtml
    return {
        id,
        mdxSource,
        data
    }
}

Rendering:
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const postData = await getPostData(params.id);
    return {
        props: {
            source: postData.mdxSource,
            postData: postData.data,
        }
    }
}

export default function Post({ source, postData }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>{postData.title}</title>
            </Head>

            <article>
                <h1 className={utilStyles.headingXl}>{postData.title}</h1>
                <div className={utilStyles.lightText}>
                    <Date dateString={postData.date} />
                </div>
                <section>
                    <MDXRemote {...source} />
                </section>
            </article>
        </Layout>
    );
}

Update:
package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.4",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "next": "12.3.4",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^3.0.1",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-p5-wrapper": "^4.1.1",
    "react-unity-webgl": "^9.4.0",
    "react-use": "17.4.0",
    "rehype-highlight": "^7.0.0",
    "remark": "^13.0.0",
    "remark-html": "^13.0.2"
  }


which node version are you using?

@Sai Node version: v12.22.9

Based on your response to my comment, try upgrading your node to a newer version. Something >= 16.9.0
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41471

That was it! Thank you! I switched to 18.20.3 and it worked.
